# Given the similar matrix A,B and A=PBP^-1 , how to find the invertible matrix P?

Tags: linear-algebra

like this :
Given $$A,B\in M_{3\times 3}(R) $$and
$$A=\begin{pmatrix}1&-3&0\\3&4&-3\\3&3&-2\end{pmatrix} $$ 
$$B=\begin{pmatrix}1&0&0\\0&1&3\\0&-3&1\end{pmatrix} $$ 
and$$A=P^{-1}BP$$
How to find the P?

---

I try to find the Jordan form of A,B ,but 
$$det(A-\lambda I)=-(\lambda-1)(\lambda^2-2\lambda+10)$$
but $$A,B\in M_{3\times 3}(R) $$   $$\lambda\in R $$ 
can't find the Jordan form?

or is there another process?

Comment: We usually use this kind of action to diagonalize a matrix, $QAQ^{-1} = D$ where D is diagonal, Presuming both A and B are diagonalizable, if we diagonalize B, then $RBR^{-1} = D$ We are told the matrices are similar so we should get to the same D, I believe (worth working out). So my thought is $ A = Q^{-1}DQ =  Q^{-1}RBR^{-1}Q = P^{1}B P$ where  $P = R^{-1} Q$

We know how to find D and Q and R with eigenvalues and eigenvectors so this is where I would start. If the matrices are not diagonalizable then that would be another issue.

Answer (score 1):

P is not unique because
if it is multiplied by
any nonsingular diagonal matrix,
$P^{-1}BP$
is the same.

Answer (score 1):

Multiplying both sides by $P$ on the left yields $PA=BP$ or $-BP+PA=C$ where $C$ is all-zero. This is called a [Sylvester equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester_equation).

The equation has a unique solution for $P$ when there are no common eigenvalues of $A$ and $B$.

Comment: It looks like you accidentally swapped P and A in the second equation.